# Help with selecting the right push button

Tags: switches

I am making a lamp that will have the following components (in order of flow of electricity from wall socket to bulb):

- Type A plug, 120 V
- On/off push button with alternate action (if I understand the terminology correctly this means press to turn on, press again to turn off, and the button surface returns to neutral position between presses)
- Rotary dimmer: I am planning on using one made for a home wall, such as one by leviton or lutron, etc.
- Light socket for A19 light bulb (the stereotypical bulb in homes) which will have a dimmable LED bulb

Here’s an visual aid:
[image]

With this arrangement the light can be kept at the desired brightness while being turned on and off. I understand that the rotary dimmers I am planning to use have on/off push buttons built in, but for this design I need a separate on/off button.

The help I am hoping to find is…
What specs should I look for in a suitable push button to ensure compatibility with the plug and the wall dimmer?

I imagine I may not be providing enough information; if so it’s just my ignorance and I will be glad to gather the needed info.

Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: Not an answer, but a web search for "SPST push-on/push-off switch" provided several possibilities.  As the answer says, you need to check both voltage and current ratings.

Answer (score 1):

You need to look for a switch that is rated for (at least) 120 V AC and (at least) as much current as your bulb will draw. If you use an incandescent bulb then remember that it draws a larger current when it is cold.